# Connection lost from mysql remote odbc with MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, remote-access

Hi I am using MS Access and have used mysql odbc to connect to a remote mysql server database. I have already set ip address on cpanel remote mysql section to allow my ms access database to connect with that. I managed to link to this database from MS Access and linked tables are imported in my ms access database but as soon as I try to open those table from ms access I get message that connection lost. What could be the reason why connection is lost when I try to open remote mysql database table in MS Access. Is this some firewall stopping it .. what could be the solution. If Cpanel has remote mysql then does it not mean that it supports remote access. I want to have a non disconnecting connection with my ms access database and possibly I have a plan to extend it to multiple users and convert this to a single database and multiple users application with each user with a copy of access database. Kindly reply thanks.

Comment: Post your connection string (obfuscate if necessary). Have you checked you firewall to ensure the port is open? What about the MySQL logs?

Comment: There is no connection string ... I am using mysql odbc and using the server url and cpanel login password to connect to a database on cpanel